# How to make 2 queryset lists but with different filter in the same view in Django

Tags: python, django

I've been searching an answer to this everywhere.
How to make 2 queryset lists but with different filter in the same view? Should I make a class and separate functions inside for each list or one function and make querysets 2 times?

Comment: can you add your question with your views, model, etc code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to append two of the same model querysets together, the following should work:

```
queryset_one = mymodel.objects.filter(id__range=[0,99])
queryset_two = mymodel.objects.filter(name__in=[john,jane])

full_queryset = queryset_one | queryset_two
```

The pipe operator is used to append querysets together.

If you need two different querysets to be passed into the view:

```
def index(request):
    queryset_one = mymodel.objects.filter(id__range=[0,99])
    queryset_two = mymodel.objects.filter(name__in=[john,jane])
    context{
        "queryset_one":queryset_one,
        "queryset_two":queryset_two
    }
    return render(request,'mypage.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your two filter for one model

```
from django.db.models import Q

Model.objects.filter(Q(x=10) | Q(active=False))
```

If for two modle

```
Q1 = model.object.filter(x=10)
Q2 = model_2.object.filter(active=False)
Q2_Q1 = Q1.union(Q2)
```